# Js module build fails on Kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

Build fails with error messages:

> ERROR in ./output.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'common'
>   in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\MultiPlatformTodo\web\web'  @ ./output.js
>   340:91-108
>
> ERROR in ./output.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kotlin'
>   in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\MultiPlatformTodo\web\web'  @ ./output.js
>   340:18-35
>
> ERROR in ./output.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'kotlin-react' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\MultiPlatformTodo\web\web' 
>   @ ./output.js 340:37-60
>
> ERROR in ./output.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'kotlin-react-dom' in
>   'C:\Users\User\Documents\MultiPlatformTodo\web\web'  @ ./output.js
>   340:62-89
>
> ERROR in ./output.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'kotlinx-coroutines-core' in
>   'C:\Users\User\Documents\MultiPlatformTodo\web\web'  @ ./output.js
>   340:110-144
>
> ERROR in ./output.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'kotlinx-html-js' in
>   'C:\Users\User\Documents\MultiPlatformTodo\web\web'  @ ./output.js
>   340:146-172
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':web:webpack-bundle'.
>     node webpack.js failed (exit code = 2)

Js module `build.gradle` is defined as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend'
apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        dependency("react", "16.6.0")
        dependency("react-dom", "16.6.0")
        dependency("@material-ui/core", "1.4.3")
    }

    sourceMaps = true

    webpackBundle {
        bundleName = "mpnotes"
        contentPath = file('src/main/web')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-js:0.6.11"
    implementation "org.jetbrains:kotlin-react:16.6.0-pre.61-kotlin-1.3.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains:kotlin-react-dom:16.6.0-pre.61-kotlin-1.3.0"
}

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions {
        outputFile = "${projectDir}/web/output.js"
        metaInfo = true
        moduleKind = "commonjs"
        sourceMap = true
    }
}
```

and `settings.gradle`:

```
enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')

rootProject.name = 'MultiPlatformTodo'
include 'android'
include 'web'
include 'common'
```

Here's the content of the `common` module:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'jvm')
        fromPreset(presets.js, 'js')
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }

        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common"
            }
        }

        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }

        jsMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the content of the `common` project build script.

Comment: @Ilya just updated the question with the `common` project

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti Any chance you could resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two likely issues.

The first is that instead of `kotlin2js` you should use multiplatform gradle plugins, ie `kotlin-multiplatform`, which is newer and will have more long-term support, or `kotlin-platform-js`, which is probably an easier drop-in replacement for your current setup.

The other problem is the line `implementation project(':common')`. This tells gradle you're consuming the common module as a js dependency, since this is a js project. For `kotlin-platform-js` you should instead use `expectedBy project(':common')` to link it as a common dependency. For `kotlin-multiplatform` there are a bunch more changes you need to your dependency configuration. You can see some details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/multiplatform-library.html)

Comment: The js module I mentioned here is not a js library, but rather a regular js module that uses the `common` library. The `kotlin2js` plugin is required to convert the kotlin code in it into js so it can be refenced in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late, but if you add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-dce-js'` in `build.gradle` you are good to go